# Are "dude" and "man" disrespectful words?

Tags: politeness, slang, greetings, forms-of-address

What is the exact nuance of *dude* or *man*?

I'm studying English from Japan. 
I want to know how people feel about *dude* or *man*.
Is it just a friendly way to call close friends?  Like addressing a boyfriend or girlfriend as *honey*? Or does it include disrespectful meaning?

In Japanese people don't use *you* if they're not close friends.  Usually they call by name or just don't say *you* because people know talking to you.
But many people call close friends *anta*, *omae*, that is meaning 'you' a lot. But *anata* is a little disrespectful and *omae* is a really disrespectful word. Maybe it's like strong "You!" or "HEY YOU!" in English.

But using like *dude* or *man* a lot. 
But in English, *dude* and *man* aren't disrespectful words? People don't feel annoyed if friends use the words?

Comment: I hope someone will provide a more detailed answer. I'll just offer this as a quick comment: _Dude_ can be a friendly name among friends – not impolite at all – but it can be considered disrepectful in other contexts (a student should not address a professor as "dude", for example). Welcome to ELL, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, well, you know, that's just like your opinion man - The dude abides.

Comment: Language is tightly intertwined with culture. As a Japanese, you may not realize that respect, while important to the individual, is not something which people in Anglosaxon cultures think/talk much about. Word choice is governed by a polite/rude consideration, not respectful/disrespectful, and this is more situation dependent. There is also the formal/informal consideration mentioned in the answers, which is even more independent of respect.

Comment: Just a quick note, rather than a full answer. There is a generational issue involved with these terms. It would usually be disrespectful to use *dude* or *man* to someone of a previous generation, such as the age of your parents or grandparents, irrespective of the context.

Comment: Short answer:  Both are informal, but not necessarily disrespectful.  You wouldn't - and shouldn't - use either to address an elder or a figure of authority, but no offense is inherent to either of them.  Among friends and peers, both are entirely respectful and quite appropriate for casual conversation.  People in the U.S. usually restrict usage of these words to friends and peers.  "Dude" used to have a slightly negative connotation, but this is no longer the case.  In modern parlance, neither word has an inherently negative or offensive connotation.

Comment: In a situation where you are talking to friends or peers, "dude" and "man" actually convey a sense of warmth and affection, because they are so informal.  A formal term would give people the impression that you aren't comfortable around them, or didn't feel at ease in their presence.  Calling a friend "dude" suggests that you are relaxed and see them as your equal, and shows that you are comfortable being with them.

Comment: @Wad Cheber: This depends very much on which particular subculture you inhabit.  Among people of a certain age & cultural background, it could be seen as friendly.  In another, it would definitely mark you as an extreme outsider.  My best advice for the OP is to listen to the people he's interacting with, and use the words they use.

Answer (score 29):

Both "dude" and "man" are INFORMAL.

Whether or not they are disrespectful depends on whether you are expected to have a formal or informal relationship with the person you are addressing.  If you have a familiar relationship already, calling them either term reinforces that familiarity.  If I say to my friend "Check this out, man!" the subtext of the message is that our relationship is such that we can use familiar terms, and it strengthens the relationship.

On the other hand if I find a traffic policeman writing me a parking ticket, and I say "You can't do that, man!" then it is disrespectful.  By using an informal term in a situation that calls for formality, I am refusing to acknowledge the authority of the other person and thus disrespecting their position.

Also, a lot depends on the TONE with which you say them.  As with any sentence, an aggressive tone makes the same word seem more offensive than a friendly tone.

See, for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77v_Q0mhbZU (0:00 to 0:45)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning, as well, that *man* can also be used in a dressing-down sort of way, lending something of a flavour of "you should know better" or "this is no time to panic". Phrases like *pull yourself together, man* or *where is your decency, man* may not be as common as they once were, but they're still current. It's taking a bit of a parental tone and can be quite formal. It's easy to distinguish in speech by intonation, but not in writing; an attempt at "archetypal hippy" can come off as "Sergeant Major" in writing if familiarity is not already well-established.

Answer (score 5):

I will also say that in an informal setting among friends, "dude!" with a certain tone is used to express surprise or dismay at something that a man has done/said. I'll give two examples.

Person 1: "I found out today that I got the job."
Person 2: "Dude! That is so awesome."

Person 1: *drunk and knocks over a glass during a party and is becoming a bit aggressive*
Person 2: "Dude, chill out."

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you watch "Dude, Where's My Car?".

As already suggested, 'dude' is typically considered an informal title.

Consider though, for a moment, Prince William hanging off a cliff. If you walked over to him and offered him your hand whilst uttering 'Dude', he would rightly accept that utterance as an invitation to be rescued, rather than an insult!

In this situation, 'dude' has become quite acceptable, and you will find that words often take on new meanings depending on the situation, and tone of voice of the speaker.

That said, you probably shouldn't go round calling everyone dude, but there are people out there that get away with doing just that, and rarely cause offence.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind the next time I rescue Prince William from the cliff.

Answer (score 1):

I will say that "dude" is definitely a more familiar word than "man". If you say "hey dude, check this out" you are definitely speaking to a good friend.

If you were in a crowded location (for example grocery store, crowded street), you might say "hey man, can I get through?" but you probably wouldn't say dude.

It should be of note that even in colloquial conversation you need to be more formal when addressing a woman. You would say "excuse me, miss" or address the woman by name.